# The war file generated by maven does not contain scala libraries

Tags: scala, maven, jboss

I have got a maven project created which contains a JAX-RS web service written using Scala. However, I found that the war file generated does not contain any scala libraries.

After I deployed it to Jboss and run, errors show that Scala libraries could not be found.

I assume maven will automatically pack any relevant libraries to WEB-INF\lib but scala is not the case.

Is there any specific configurations I need to add in order for the scala library to be packed?

Or shall I place scala to anywhere local to the JBoss AS?

Many thanks!

**Update:**

I actually have found out why the scala libraries are not included in the war. It was because I defined a "provided" scope for the scala dependency.

However, if I include scala in the war, the deployment will fail with an illegal argument exception.

I brief remember I used to config jboss to use local copy of scala library, but I forgot how to do this.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Many thanks